# PHP Session Security for Website Login

Tags: php, security, session, ssl, login-script

I'm creating a login script for a website i'm developing, and am using PHP sessions to authenticate users.

I've set the script to use HTTP only for the cookies, and to only use cookies for storing the session ID.

Basically, I'd like to know two things

**1.** Is there anything more I should do to make my login more secure?

and

**2.** The PHP Manual says that `session_destroy()` deletes the session data, but doesn't unset any of the session variables. If this is the case, what is it actually destroying, and should I manually unset my session variables on logout?

Thanks for any help

**EDIT:**
I am using free hosting, and cannot install any Apache addons or change the php.ini file

**EDIT:**
I've read that using SSL is required to stop the session ID from being stolen, but I don't have the ability to install OpenSSL on the server, so is there some other way I could protect the session ID?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The most important thing to remember:

> Don't trust ANYTHING that comes back from the client

Never assume that the information you are getting (in a form field (even hidden ones), session variables, etc.) are valid - use server-side logic to perform these checks.

1.) Make sure your session is encrypted. If you are using PHP's built-in sessions, the associated entropy (randomness) is relatively high, so you should be fine.

2.) ONLY store the session id in the cookie. Any other information should simply be associated on the server using that id. I've seen many cases where the system engineer determines if someone is admin if the token 'is_admin' = true in the session. You can obviously see the problem with this.

Some will complain that its an expensive operation, but I recommend creating a (my)SQL table for active sessions. Then, when the page is loaded, pull the associated data from the table and deal with it just as you would any other data. Some frameworks (like CodeIgnitor) do this for you by changing one configuration item.

3.) Validate against IP - in your table, add the current IP address. If the current IP doesn't match the one in the session, someone is probably trying to hijack. Force a logout and terminate.

4.) Place limits on login attempts. Adding a 1 second sleep(); server side on each login is virtually unnoticeable to the user, but for an automated system, it makes it virtually impossible to brute force logins.

5.) Watch being 'too chatty'. In a login, you may think it's helpful to give descriptive erros like 'username doesn't exist' or 'incorrect password'. Information like this tells a hacker that they have gotten a valid username - it makes hacking much faster.

6.) Be less concerned about the safety of PHP and SSL and more of your own logic. Just because a website uses SSL doesn't make it secure. SSL coupled with valid logic provides security.

7.) If you're SUPER concerned, you'll want to move to a dedicated server. It's possible that other websites hosted on your server could have access to your code/db information. They may not be taking the necessary steps to be as secure as you.

8.) Don't allow simultaneous sessions. This prevents a MITM (man in the middle) attack. Another advantage of the DB session approach is that you can force logouts if two clients are trying to login at the same time from different IPs. Yet another advantage to the DB approach is that it makes your system scalable (since session storage is filesystem dependent).

9.) Use mysql_real_escape_string instead of add_slashes

If you need more information on security with PHP, it's a speciality of mine. Feel free to contact me.

Answer (score 1):

The important thing to understand here is where the data is stored - sessions are stored server-side, so nothing in a session is ever sent to the client unless you intentionally include it in a page. The Id is supposed to be random and non-deterministic (ie un-guessable).

This means that you can use a session to store keys, Ids, etc and never worry about the user being able to find out what they are.

When you `session_destroy()`, you're clearing the server-side link between the Id and the variables rendering the session unusable. The client may still have the Id but it's now useless.

It's not possible to comment on how secure your implementation is without some idea of what you're actually doing - but storing information in sessions is far far better than directly in cookies/form data

EDIT: Re your SSL Question:

SSL Is supported on almost every modern server. (You really have to hunt for a server which doesn't support it). OpenSSL is one of *many* pieces of software which implement SSL.

The basics of SSL are as follows: You get a certificate* which is installed on the server. The server uses this certificate to "sign" every request and encrypt transmissions between client and server.

*Certificates can be created for free (Google " *self-sign certificates* ") but self-sign certificates usually give the user a warning/error depending on the browser (as there's no level of trust implied). Browsers have a list of "trusted" certificate issuers - Verisign, Thawte, and many more. These are well established companies who issue certificates (usually for a fee).

Certificate are valid for a certain time period and have varying levels of trust (eg cheap ones simply verify your email address is correct, *Extended Verification* certificates are only issued after phone numbers, passports, email addressess and registered address have been verified by the issuer).

There are some advantages to EV certificates (as well as a padlock icon, you get a green address bar - see www.paypal.com ) You'll need to decide how important that is to you.

You should contact your host to ask if/how you can add an SSL certificate. It used to be that this was usually only available for paid accounts but it's becoming far more common nowadays - so you're like to find free SSL hosting if you Google a bit

Comment: Sorry, you missed something out there - states what? If you call `session_destroy`, you could still use `$_SESSION['SomeVar']` for the duration of that script as it's already been populated but another request from the client would mean re-reading the session data which would no longer be present. `sessions_destroy()` is usually called on logout before a redirect so this is not an issue.

Answer (score 1):

1) Use https. At a bare minimum the login page **must** use https to protect the user's password, but you should consider making the whole authenticated session use https to prevent cookie stealing.

Require both cookie and POST data to contain the correct authentication token.

You could also consider changing the authentication token on each request to prevent session fixation. I'd recommend you read up on how to prevent cross-site request forgery and other similar attacks. [OWASP](http://owasp.org) is a good resource for getting general information about common attacks and how to mitigate them.

2) `session_destroy` essentially invalidates the client's session cookie so future requests will not see the same session data. Depending on your code flow you can either make `session_destroy` the last thing you do before returning to the client, or you can manually unset the `$_SESSION` superglobal contents.

Comment: So... If I used session_destroy(), there is no way that those session variables could be access again?

Comment: Umm... I don't know how to activate HTTPS, or think that I can get HTTPS with my free hosting, is there some way around this?

Comment: Good point re: XSS. I peronally prefer to avoid checking POSTED data againt a constantly changing server-side var as it breaks multiple-tab usage. This may, however, be desired. My online banking uses that technique and I hate it - using the back button or clicking a link twice results in an auth failure. I can understand _why_ they do it (esp. for banking) but it is a serious usability issue.

Comment: @Jasper: The variables still exist until you end the current request. After that they should be gone forever.

Comment: To get HTTPs you need to get a SSL certificate (GoDaddy.com are the cheapest but that's about the only thing going for them). You then need to install the SSL cert on your server. Most user control panels allow for this nowadays but you would need to check with your host.

Comment: @Jasper: If you cannot use SSL then you're in trouble. An attacker can just sniff username/password pairs as they go past. Fixing this by hashing client-side is possible, but difficult. SSL is by far the best way to secure login requests.

Comment: Is there a free hosting service that allows for this, or would I have to go to paid hosting?

Comment: @Jasper: I don't know the answer to that one, sorry.

Answer (score 0):

I would use [session_regenerate_id()](http://ca.php.net/session_regenerate_id) every time the user elevates their level of privilege (for example by logging in). I know you said you can't use SSL but you should really consider it if the info being transmitted is at all sensitive. session_regenerate_id() in combination with SSL provides the strongest defence against session hijacking. You should consider if free hosting is really giving you what you need if you're holding any sort of sensitive information.

Answer (score 0):

I'm working on a login script and followed every step listed by @sethvargo as described the first and the most important thing is to check weather the data is sent by a trusted source or not? Fir this purpose I usually do is that I create a special token and embed it in the form it's like something like this.

```
hash('md5', 'special-phrase_' . time() . '_special-phrase');
```

And on the receiving side I run a loop which works like this. The token will be of no use after 1 minute.

```
for ($i=0; $i<=60; $i++) {
    $phrase = hash('md5', 'special-phrase_' . (time() - $i) . '_special-phrase');
    if ($phrase == $token) {
        print('Request received from a trusted client.'); exit;
    }
}
print ('Request timeout!')!
```

I'm using this technique in my login system, is this right way to deal trusted data? Please give your suggestions.
Thanks!